# How to install jquery using typings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

used:

```
typings install jquery --global

typings ERR! message Unable to find "jquery" ("npm") in the registry. Did you want to try searching another source? Also, if you want contribute these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/jquery/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200
```

Could anyone help me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try:

```
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

EDIT:

from https://github.com/typings/typings#updating-from-0x-to-10

> If you want to install from DefinitelyTyped, be explicit (use dt~ --global). For example: typings install dt~angular-component-router --global --save

(see also Fidan Hakaj's comment below)

Comment: But what does it exactly mean?

Comment: @Andrey It stands for DefinitelyTyped. 
Seen in typings README file : If you want to install from DefinitelyTyped, be explicit (use dt~<pkg> --global).
https://github.com/typings/typings#updating-from-0x-to-10

Comment: how can I use it now? i still don't see jquery*.ts files

Comment: @PhilippMunin this installs a `.d.ts` in `typings/global/jquery`

Answer (score 8):

If you are using typescript2.0 with the command:

> npm install -g typescript@2.0

You can install jquery with the command:

> npm install --save @types/jquery

Comment: While this works, it blows out the `$` variable globally which is problematic for using it with a lot of other typings libraries. See here for a potential fix of namespacing `$` as `jquery`.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11187